# Extract vertical and horizontal alignment from DataGridViewContentAlignment

Tags: .net, enums, bit-manipulation

I am trying to test a value of the following type for the horizontal alignment:

```
public enum DataGridViewContentAlignment
{
    NotSet = 0,
    TopLeft = 1,
    TopCenter = 2,
    TopRight = 4,
    MiddleLeft = 16,
    MiddleCenter = 32,
    MiddleRight = 64,
    BottomLeft = 256,
    BottomCenter = 512,
    BottomRight = 1024,
}
```

For example, I would like to write a single test that returns true if the Aligneent is XXXLeft. Is there a compact way to write it instead of three or clauses?

Comment: So, you're looking for something like `(value & 0x111) != 0`?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Why don't you put that as answer?

Comment: Are you sure? Because it only *close* to what you asked for. It doesn't actually test whether the alignment is one of three things, it's testing whether the alignment contains at least one XXXLeft.